# Cannot access array element. use result of one ajax request to another ajax request

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, asynchronous, api-eveonline

```
    //global variables
var corpArray = new Array(); //store corp classes instances
var corpId = new Array(); //store corp id's

window.onload = init();

function init() {
  getNpcCorpId();
  console.log(corpId);
  getCorpNames(corpId[5]);
}

//get all corporation id's from the game
function getNpcCorpId() {
  let conName = new XMLHttpRequest();
  conName.onload = function() {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      let idList = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      idList.forEach(element => {
        corpId.push(element);
      });
    }
  };
  conName.open(
    "get",
    "https://esi.evetech.net/latest/corporations/npccorps/?datasource=tranquility",
    true
  );
  conName.send();
}

//get corporation name
function getCorpNames(element) {
  console.log(element);
  let corpConn = new XMLHttpRequest();
  corpConn.onload = () => {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  corpConn.open(
    "get",
    `https://esi.evetech.net/latest/corporations/${element}/?datasource=tranquility`,
    true
  );
  corpConn.send();
}
```

I am trying to create an eve online api, i want to use 2 global varibles to store my retrieved values (because i do not know another way) i will use a couple of functions to use the provieded eve api.I can not acces my corpId individual elements, when i console log all my array ,everything is ok,but when i want to access individual element it appears undefiend.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 //global variables
var corpArray = new Array(); //store corp classes instances
var corpId = new Array(); //store corp id's

window.onload = init();

async function  init() {
  await getNpcCorpId();
  console.log(corpId);
  getCorpNames(corpId[5]);            // asynchronous behaviour - let it be fix using await and async
}

//get all corporation id's from the game
function getNpcCorpId() {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  let conName = new XMLHttpRequest();
  conName.onload = function() {
   if (this.status == 200) {
     let idList = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
     idList.forEach(element => {
    corpId.push(element);
     });
   }
   resolve();
  };
  conName.open(
    "get",
    "https://esi.evetech.net/latest/corporations/npccorps/?datasource=tranquility",
    true
  );
  conName.send();
 
});

  
}

//get corporation name
function getCorpNames(element) {
  console.log(element);
  let corpConn = new XMLHttpRequest();
  corpConn.onload = () => {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  corpConn.open(
    "get",
    `https://esi.evetech.net/latest/corporations/${element}/?datasource=tranquility`,
    true
  );
  corpConn.send();
}
```

> This is due to asynchronous behaviour - in simple terms - when you
>   call getNpcCorpId() it is a http request it will take some time to
>   execute but next line run immediately so at that point of time corpId
>   is still blank. So to fix this issue you can use await that will makes
>   JavaScript wait until the promise returns a result.

Hope this helps you !